# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Вопрос наверное глупый, но всё же)

Tags: laravel

Когда я меняю в env файле эти значения:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=element
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

на эти

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE="test"
DB_USERNAME="test"
DB_PASSWORD="test123"
```

выдаёт эту ошибку:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Кэш чистил и другие простые манипуляции в консоли делал не помогает.
На локальном сервере и на хостинге одинаково.

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test'@'localhost';`?

Comment: а вместо DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 указать DB_HOST=localhost ?

Comment: хостинг в сторону пока что. На локале вы меняете имя базы, юзера и пароль в конфиге пхп, какими-то действиями на стороне СУБД это подкреплено? Там база существует, юзер с паролем создан, и права на базу выданы?